# Lync for OS X: group order

Tags: macos, lync

Is there a way to change the order in which groups are displayed in the Lync contact list?

I am using Lync 14.0.2.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't drag and drop work?

Comment: @user1301428 No, the groups are draggable but they are grayed out and there is not effects whatsoever when dropping them